# Javascript - Add a line break into a variable

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I am starting on Javascript and I really have no idea how to put a linebreak into a variable:

I would like to build the following triangle without using print, just putting the result into a string :

Any idea ?
Thanks

```
        #
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######


var creerTriangle= function (taille) {
    var triangle = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= taille; i++) {
       var ligne = "";
        for (var j=1; j <= (taille-i); j++) {
        ligne+=(" ");
          }
        for (var k=1; k<=i; k++) {
           ligne += "#";
          }       
         triangle += ligne              // how to put a linebreak here ?;
    };
 return triangle;
};
```

Comment: add an \n or br?

Comment: "\n" is the new line character, where are you placing this text on your web page, because depending on the element type, it may not work with newline

Comment: Just ```triangle += ligne + '\n'```

Comment: that's right. Forgot I had to print the function  print(creerTriangle(n)) instead of just creerTriangle(n), for it to print the triangle. Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need "\n". See where I've written <---

```js
/*      #
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
   */


var creerTriangle= function (taille) {
  var triangle = "";

  for (var i = 1; i <= taille; i++) {
    var ligne = "";
    for (var j=1; j <= (taille-i); j++) {
        ligne+=(" ");
    }
        for (var k=1; k<=i; k++) {
           ligne += "#";
        }         
         triangle += ligne +"\n"  //<--- 
    };
 return triangle;
};

console.dir(creerTriangle(6));
```

Comment: that's right. Forgot I had to print the function  print(creerTriangle(n)) instead of just creerTriangle(n), for it to print the triangle. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is another way to write this with ESNEXT:

```js
const creerTriangle = tally =>
    Array(tally)
        .fill()
        .map(() => '#'.repeat(tally))
        .map((i, index) =>
            i.replace(new RegExp(`#{${index}}`), ' '.repeat(index))
        )
        .reverse()
        .join('\n')

console.log(creerTriangle(6))
```

https://repl.it/@ryanpcmcquen/javascriptCreateTriangle